# How to make a Group By in PostgreSQL with only one field?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

```
SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1, table2.field1
GROUP BY table1.field1
```

MySQL: ✅ All right!

PostgreSQL: ❌ You must put all Select fields in the Group By!

How to make a Group By in PostgreSQL with only one field?

Comment: Which aggregate function are you using?

Comment: Use MAX(table2.field2) or MIN(table2.field2) if you want to use single group by

Comment: It's not "all right" with MySQL. Instead of throwing an error MySQL simply chooses to return random results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if table2.field2 value is alpha numeric then use MIN/MAX or table2.field2 is numeric then use any aggregate function as per need for avoiding to use table2.field2 column in GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT table1.field1
     , MAX(table2.field2) field2  
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
       ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
GROUP BY table1.field1
```